# R - How to elegantly apply a function to matrix columns, feeding result back into the function call on next column?

Tags: r

Learning R and new to functional languages, stuck on this.

I have a function with the following signature:

```
Control <- FUN(SEED=vector(int, float), DATA=vector(float)) yields RESULT=vector(int, float)
```

I have a matrix M with float entries

I want to apply FUN to each column of M in turn, as the DATA argument, using the RESULT of the previous FUN call as SEED to the FUN call on the next matrix column.

The loop unwound, what I mean is this:

```
1) FUN(SEED=(1, 0), DATA=M_c1) #no previous result at the start, so specify
(yields RESULT_1)

2) FUN(SEED=RESULT_1, DATA=M_c2)
.
.
.
n) FUN(SEED=RESULT_n, DATA=M_cn)
```

RESULT_(n+1) is then the end of the computation.

I've been looking at the APPLY function family, but I'm not seeing how I can feed results back into FUN subsequent FUN calls.

Am I missing something with the APPLY family? Is there some other way this sort of thing is done in the R/functional world? I know a FOR loop can be done, but I was under the impression that such constructs are considered bad practice in R world - what the "R way" to do this?

Any ideas appreciated,

sff

Comment: Sounds like a `for` loop is ideal for this situation. Anything where the next result relies on the previous is typically hard to vectorize. There are `?Reduce` and `?Recall`, which might be useful depending on the exact problem.

Comment: It sounds like you data may be wide when it should be long. It is much easier to reference a lagged observation than the previous positional column.

Comment: @thelatemail - bah i already know how to use for loops :) i'll look at reduce/recall tho - thx!

Comment: @RyanKnight - my matrix is specifically constructed to be as close to square as possible, actually - via nrow=floor(sqrt(length(vector)). Regardless, I could easily restructure the matrix so as to successively feed rows to FUN instead, if that would make any appreciable difference. Can you explain how it would? thx!